# I am getting a High volume of request on my server

Tags: security, ssh, server, port

I have never changed a server setting in my entire job career, but recently I have received many complaints from employees that websites sometimes get crashed, are slow to load, or don't load at all. So I did a search on Google and checked that I was getting heavy requests on the server the ddos attack. so i seen many ways to prevent this, so i did nmap and checked the open port all are fine expect the one which is open 22/tcp    open  ssh can this be a problem ??

Can 22/tcp open ssh? ssh the reason for a DDOS attack on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent ddos ​​attacks by simply closing ports. Ddos is basically activating a process that requires more processing than your processing power. I think there is enough information in this resource. You can check

https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-survive-a-ddos-attack/